# Potential EU Tax Residency and Ownership of US ETFs

Tags: etf, european-union, europe, tax-residency

I'm currently considering the possibility of obtaining EU tax residency in the future, and I'm aware of the restrictions that EU tax residents face when it comes to purchasing US-based ETFs due to regulatory constraints. However, I currently own some US ETFs.

I'm curious about what would happen to my existing US ETF holdings if I were to obtain EU tax residency in the future:

Could I retain my current US ETF holdings and continue to collect dividends from them, or would I be required to sell them immediately upon becoming an EU tax resident?

Comment: What restrictions are you talking about? AFAIK there's no law in any European country forbidding you to have US holdings. Also, worth mentioning that EU is not a country and there's no such thing as "EU tax resident".

Comment: @littleadv According to [link](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/E-9-2021-004745_EN.html#def2) `Since 2018, ordinary investors in the European Union cannot invest in US exchange-traded funds`

Comment: This doesn't preclude you from investing, it just doesn't allow brokers to offer it to you if the rule applies to them

Comment: @littleadv I'm sorry, but I don't think you are correct. I can see a lot of information on the internet that states there are two alternatives for EU investors: EU-domiciled ETFs(similar to US-domiciled) and UCITS. However, there is no information available about the case when an investor __gains__ EU tax residency.

Comment: There's no such thing "EU tax residence". The rule you're quoting applies to funds. It doesn't prohibit you from holding them, it prohibits them from marketing to you. If you buy them outside EU you break no laws.

Comment: @littleadv EU tax residence means tax residence in any EU country. All of them share this common regulation established at the European Parliament level.

Comment: Right, maybe, but as I said - this regulation applies to the funds, not the investors. It doesn't prohibit you from owning the funds, it prohibits the funds/brokers from marketing to you. So you can't *buy* them through a EU-regulated broker, but if you already have them - good for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Interactive Brokers support, IB is required to provide Key Information Documents to retail customers in the European Economic Area and the United Kingdom for certain financial instruments. However, US ETFs typically do not provide KIDs, so trading of US ETFs is blocked for EEA and UK retail customers.

Orders from retail investors in the EEA or the UK related to products not complying with the EU's PRIIPS Regulation will be rejected. This regulation aims to improve understanding of financial products by providing KIDs with information on product description, costs, risks, and performance.

These rules apply to all retail clients in the EEA or the UK and to corporate accounts classified as MiFID Retail, but not to MiFID Professional customers.

**One can still hold or close existing positions subject to PRIIPs regulation, but opening new positions or increasing existing ones in these instruments is not allowed.**

Answer (score 0):

I'll summarize the discussion we had in the comments.

The European Union regulations require that any fund marketed to the EU citizens through EU-regulated brokers would provide a KID (Key Investor Document), which among other things should provide some expectations (speculations?) about future performance. You linked to and quoted from a EU parliament member's [question](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/E-9-2021-004745_EN.html#def2), here's what [the answer](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/E-9-2021-004745-ASW_EN.html) says:

> Directive 2011/61/EU[4] qualifies non-EU investment funds as alternative investment funds (AIFs). Under that directive, non-EU AIFs may be offered to retail investors provided a given Member State allows (i) marketing of such funds in its territory and (ii) marketing of such funds to retail investors.
>
> In accordance with Regulation 1286/2014, AIFs offered to retail investors must either draw up the Undertakings for the Collective Investment in Transferable Securities (UCITS) key investor information document[5] or the Packaged Retail Investment and Insurance-Based Products (PRIIPs) Key Information Document.

It appears that the US funds cannot comply with the requirements of neither PRIIPs nor UCITS due to the US regulation, and as such are not available through EU-regulated brokers.

But, neither the question nor the answer say or imply that EU citizens are *required* to only invest through EU-regulated brokers, or in EU-regulated funds. Thus, if you already have holdings in US ETFs - there's nothing, at least in the links you provided, that prevents you from keeping it. Similarly, if you have access to a US broker and you invest in US ETFs there - you can continue doing so (tax and reporting compliance aside).

You may have troubles transferring that holding into a EU-regulated brokerage. In some countries you may end up not being allowed to have foreign accounts or have additional reporting requirements about them (check the country you're interested in). But as a general rule, there's no prohibition for any EU tax resident (i.e.: tax resident of any EU member country) to hold US ETFs, the prohibition is only on the funds and brokers to sell them.